# Monkey-patching, duck-typing and argument self

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I try to monkey-patch a class with a method from another class, it doesn't work because the argument `self` isn't of the right type.

For example, let's like the result of the method `__str__` created by the fancy class `A`:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, val):
       self.val=val
   def __str__(self):
       return "Fancy formatted %s"%self.val
```

and would like to reuse it for a boring class `B`:

```
class B:
   def __init__(self, val):
       self.val=val
```

That means:

```
 >>> b=B("B") 

 >>> #first try:
 >>> B.__str__=A.__str__
 >>> str(b)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: unbound method __str__() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)


 >>> #second try:
 >>> B.__str__= lambda self: A.__str__(self)
 >>> str(b)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
 TypeError: unbound method __str__() must be called with A instance as first argument (got B instance instead)
```

So in both cases the it doesn't work because the argument `self` should be an instance of class `A`, but evidently isn't.

It would be nice to find a way to do the monkey-patching, but my actual question is, why it is necessary for the implicit parameter `self` to be an instance of the "right" class and not just depend on the duck-typing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the way methods are contributed to class objects in Python 2, the actual function object is hidden behind an unbound method, but you can access it using the [`im_func`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) aka `__func__` attribute:

```
>>> B.__str__ = A.__str__.__func__
>>> str(B('stuff'))
'Fancy formatted stuff'
```

Arguably, a better way to do this is using new-style classes and inheritance.

```
class MyStrMixin(object):
   def __str__(self):
       return "Fancy formatted %s" % self.val
```

Then inherit from `MyStrMixin` in both `A` and `B`, and just let the [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) do its thing.